# How var type decide data type at run time when Iterating ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#

I have C# ArrayList and added two items int and string type
Now in for loop Item returns and captured in var type at run time.
How this var type decide data type at compile time????

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

al.Add(10);

al.Add("A");

for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
    var val = al[i];
    Console.WriteLine("type of value is {0} and {1}",val.GetType(),val);
}
```

Comment: All the information you need is here in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ArrayList_Item_System_Int32_

Answer (score 2):

`var` is used for type inference at compile time. The compiler determines the variable type given all the information it has about the expression `al[i]` at that time.

Since the [indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) of `ArrayList` is of type `object`, the compiler infers the type of `val` to be `object`.

At runtime, when calling `val.GetType()` you have access to the actual type of `val`: either `int` or `string` in your case. But the type of the `val` variable is still `object`.

The same mechanism happens if you write:

```
object o = new int();
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```

You'd see "System.Int32" although the type of o is `object`.

[Link to fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1EIhbm)

Answer (score 1):

`var` is purely compiler "magic", nothing special happens at runtime.

It's your way of saying "compiler, you figure out the correct data type for this variable declaration. I either don't want to, am not too concerned about the specific type, or it's got an unpronounceable name<sup>1</sup>"

So, the compiler first works out the data type of the expression that's being used to initialize the variable, and gives the variable that type.

Here, the expression's simple - you're accessing the [`Item` property of `ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ArrayList_Item_System_Int32_) via C#'s indexer syntax. That property returns `object`, so that's the type of the `val` variable.

All of that happens at compile time.

---

<sup>1</sup>When LINQ was introduced, anonymous types arrived in the language. These are real types generated by the compiler, but they're deliberately given names that, whilst valid names so far as the CLR is concerned, aren't valid names so far as C# is concerned. You don't know their names and even if you did, you wouldn't write them in C#.

It's why `var` *had* to be added to the language, the other reasons are convenient outcomes of that decision.

Answer (score 0):

As other said here ArrayList implementation is based on object. Var only infers the type of the right side of the assignment, which in this case is a type of an object, feel free to use in this case object. You should not get any exception. Because ArrayList has not a generic implementation you need to unbox the items to a specific type if you want to treat them differently. 
Basically you have a similar effect using a generic list of object.

Here is the implementation of the class, so you can see by yourself the internal implementation

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs

Hope this helps